# QT Application throws exception when trying to show window

Tags: c++, qt

After a year of working fine, I went to debug my program today and for the first time was greeted with the following error with the program stopping in some disassembler code:

```
"The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception. 
Stopped in thread 0 by: Exception at 0x77bb1f5f, code: 0xc0000005: read access 
violation at: 0xffffffffbaadf00c, flags=0x0, (first chance)."
```

My code is simplified to the following:

```c++
class DeviceChooser : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit DeviceChooser(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~DeviceChooser();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    a.setApplicationName(APP_NAME);
    a.setApplicationVersion(APP_VERSION);
    a.setOrganizationName(APP_ORGANISATION_NAME);

    a.setWindowIcon(icon);

    return startApplicationNormal(a);
}

int    startApplicationNormal(QApplication &a)
{
    DeviceChooser w;

    QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), &w, SLOT(applicationClosing()) );

    w.show();   // <-- if i step over this, the error appears
    return a.exec();
}
```

I'm not sure really why this is happening. I've reinistalled my environment and my compilers, and even uninstalled and reinstalled visual studio build tools that I was previously using with the same result. I have also tried different compiler configurations in my build settings but no luck.

What's odd is that if I press "run" after the exception is caught, the program will run as expected as if nothing happened.

I am using QT 5.14.0 with qwt 6.1.3.

The stack trace through the disassembler (program stops on second line):

```
0x7769448b   <+   27>        mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp-4]
0x77bb1f5f   <+  127>        cmp     word ptr [eax],dx
```

Comment: A first chance exception is one that was thrown but may still be caught and handled. Normally you'd want to ignore these in the debugger settings since they are not necessarily a problem you need to worry about. If it turns into an unhandled exception, meaning it was not caught and dealt with, then you have a real problem.

Comment: Very suspicious that it tries to read `0xffffffffbaadf00c` -- That suggests a signed 32-bit value `0xbaadf00d` was cast to a pointer and had 1 subtracted. That particular value is commonly used as a debugging filler to detect when something has become invalid (_e.g._ pointer to memory that was freed), or to pre-initialize memory to detect uninitialized values.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Turning off "first chance" exceptions stops that message from appearing, however the program still stops in the disassembler. I've added the disassembler lines to the original post. Not sure if that will be much help. I ended up even trying to reinstall my entire QT setup with no luck. Really strange how this has happened...

Comment: Are you able to step *into* `w.show()` rather than over it? Also, what else is on the call stack?

Comment: @jkb tried that. it throws the error as soon as I step into it

Comment: What do the definitions of `DeviceChooser`'s constructor and destructor look like?